# Affordable helpdesk+invoicing/billing/CRM with API? (alternative to WHMCS for non web hosts)

Tags: self-hosted, crm, invoicing, help-desk, lamp

I am looking for something that can provide a helpdesk, a decent api and excellent invoicing/billing/crm features, at either a more affordable price, or ideally an open source solution.

Can anyone recommend anything?

NOTE: It needs to run on a typical LAMP stack.

*We use [WHMCS](http://www.whmcs.com) because we are a webhosting company. It's perfect for that, but we also realised it can be used for other purposes. Specifically, we have started using parts of WHMCS for other businesses for these reasons:
 - Excellent Invoicing / Billing / CRM
 - Excellent Helpdesk
 - Decent API with an "Internal API" option.
The problem is, WHMCS is most likely as expensive as it is because of the web host specific features it provides. And it's gotten even more expensive now that they limit it by number of clients.*

Comment: By billing, do you mean you need integration with payment systems? Also, what should the API provide?

Comment: I mean like as in it supports invoicing. Not too concerned about what payment methods it supports. And API... have a look at what WHMCS's api provides: https://developers.whmcs.com/api/api-index/ ... create order, create invoice, add user, delete user etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions for you. One is [BoxBilling](http://www.boxbilling.com) 
That is open source and is very easy to integrate in your platform. They have a free/pro license depending of your needs. API and several integrations with other manufacturers.

The other one is [ZBillingNET](http://www.zbillingnet.com)
Also with 3rd partnership integration and WebAPI.

You have to see if their integrations meets your needs.